# Can a Kage Bunshin make another Kage Bunshin?

Tags: naruto

Can a Kage Bunshin make another Kage Bunshin?

Sometimes you see the clones die and I am screaming at the TV, why didn't that clone just make a clone of itself before it died?

Or does Naruto tend to let them die on purpose so he can gain their knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

In short: **Yes**.

There are several instances where Naruto will create several Shadow Clones, which in turn create more Shadow Clones.

As far as why he doesn't create any more, this is speculative. I can think of a few reasons:

- Naruto doesn't possess the skill to do so. The useful part of a clone creating a clone right before "death" would be to gain tactical advantage. Naruto's strategy is generally to "charge right in", while this kind of strategy would rely on the clones "dying" so as to be the bait for a new clone coming right in.
- There simply isn't enough reaction time. Naruto has demonstrated that it takes time to create clones, even if the amount of time is relatively small. Rather than take the time to mold chakra and perform the technique, why not actually fight?

Comment: Adding to this, Creating a new clone will share the chakra from the original... Since a shadow clone will already have only less amount of chakra and it can't fuse new chakra for itself, making new clone is not possible/is not effective...

Comment: There's nothing that says a clone cannot "fuse" new chakra for itself. Clones can mold chakra just as well as the original, the only real limitation is the reduced chakra pool.

Answer (score 0):

I see two questions here

1. why didn't clones create another clone before they die?

   A. As we know that clones dispel when they are hit by a force enough to severely hurt them. Image this very thin instance where the clone realizes he is about to die, what amount of chakra does a clone have in that instance, likely very minimal. If he tries to make a clone then, he actually has to divide his chakra, which will further diminish his chakra resource. In this case, he might actually quicken his death, or miraculously if he succeeds in making a clone with such minimal amount of chakra, I don't think the clone is of any use in the fight.
2. Does Naruto tend to let clones die on purpose to gain knowledge ?

   A. More or less **YES**, because clones act on their own, they have their own conscience and they can use full abilities of his caster(who made the clones). They go head on with their opponent. It's a better strategy to learn opponent abilities quickly. Answering you question, its depends on the situation, not every time Naruto purposefully let's clones dispel, even though users have ability to control their clone chakra.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can.
Kage Bunshin making Kage Bunshin is called Tajuu Kage Bunshin.
you can see it from the interval and placement of the new clones.